# How to add (append) user in multiuser picker field using jira-python

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I have been trying to append user to the existing multi-user picker field without replacing users in it.

Ex:
The Jira JQL finds the user rkapoor in the *Testers* field, then append rkapoor1 to the *Testers* field

Note: The Testers field might contain other users along with rkapoor (just wanted append, not to replace other users)

```
for issue in jira.search_issues('project = "ABC" and issuetype = Epic and status not in (Closed) and Testers in (rkapoor)', maxResults=100):
testuser = jira.user('rkapoor1')
testlist = issue.fields.customfield_10600
testlist.append(testuser)
issue.update(fields={"customfield_10600": [testlist]})
```

Console error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "Jiratest1.py", line 32, in
>  issue.update(fields={"customfield_10600": [testlist]}) File
> "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\jira\resources.py", line 485,
> in update super(Issue, self).update(async_=async_, jira=jira,
> notify=notify, fields=data) File
> "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\jira\resources.py", line 225,
> in update data = json.dumps(data) File
> "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\json_*init*_.py", line 231, in dumps``
> return _default_encoder.encode(obj) File
> "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
> chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True) File
> "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
> return _iterencode(o, 0) File
> "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
> raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} ' TypeError:
> Object of type User is not JSON serializable

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution,

```
testuser = jira.user('rkapoor1')
testlist = issue.fields.customfield_10600
testlist.append(testuser)
new_assignees = [{"name": str(u.name)} for u in testlist] 
issue.update(fields={"customfield_10600": new_assignees})
```